# RTX 3070 is not detected with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics

Recently, I built a PC with the following specs:

- Intel Core i9-10850K
- Asus PRIME Z590-P
- Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB DDR4
- Kingston A2000 1 TB SSD
- GeForce RTX 3070 8GB

The computer turns on, boots Ubuntu, and functions like a normal PC. Nothing is broken, that is, until I noticed that Ubuntu can't see the Nvida card. I checked `lspci` in the terminal, and the only device that outputs video is my CPU's integrated graphics. I tried installing multiple different versions of Nvida drivers through terminal (not at the same time) to no avail. There is no mention of needed drivers in the Software Updates application. If I plug my HDMI cable into the graphics card (instead of the motherboard), it doesn't output any signal, and my monitor goes into power saving mode; it doesn't even give output in BIOS! When I turn on my power supply, a small red LED lights up on the card, so it is getting power. I've tried putting it in the second PCI slot, again, to no avail. And I've tried clearing the RTC of my motherboard. When I run `nvidia-settings` in terminal, I get an error saying that it couldn't communicate with the card. I've also disabled secure boot in the BIOS (I heard that it can mess with the loading of the Nvidia drivers) and the still doesn't fix the problem. The only time that the computer acknowledged the card, was when I first installed Ubuntu. It mentioned something about Nvidia's proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the red light was telling me to plug in a second power cable! The tutorial I was watching only plugged in one, which threw me off!